# Impossible to create a new React project

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a new react project (I work on Mac OS).

To do that, according the [documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/), I enter this :

```
npx create-react-app bet-front
```

I obtain this error :

> yarn add v1.3.2
> [1/4]   Resolving packages...
> [2/4]   Fetching packages...
> error @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@2.24.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^8.10.0 || ^10.13.0 || >=11.10.1".
> error Found incompatible module

I updated my node version ([here](https://nodejs.org/en/)), I have now : v12.16.2

I updated npm version, I have now : 6.14.4

Despite these upgrades, I have the same errors to create a new react project. Do I have the right versions of these tools to create a new react project ? What can I do more ?

### Edit 1

I already tried this without success, and same error : `npm init react-app bet-front`

### Edit 2

I uninstalled node and npm and re installed it. And then retried the command to create a new React project. And no changes : same error about the `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@2.24.0`.

Comment: I think you should upgrade  @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@2.24.0 to  @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@2.29.0 to install: npm i @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@2.29.0

Comment: Thanks Samim. I just tried to update this @typescript-eslint. And then I re tried the command **npx create-react-app bet-front** . Unfortunately, same errors.

Comment: Double check your node and npm are updated successfully or not open your terminal and write: node -v And npm -v. Sometimes it happens that people miss this.

Comment: I already checked the versions with these commands. And it s correct. node : 12.16.2 and npm 6.14.4

Comment: From documentation I found that you have to install/update @typescript-eslint/parser to latest version, I hope this works to you. npm i @typescript-eslint/parser@2.29.0

Comment: I already tried this, without success. I am waiting a little bit and I will try to uninstall completely node/npm. thanks again for your help.

Comment: What is `npx -v`? or `npx -- node -v`

Comment: Hi HMR. npx -v ==> 6.14.4 and npx -- node -v ==> 11.6.0

Answer (score 0):

I finally succeeded to create this new react project :

```
sudo npm i -g create-react-app
```

I do not know why it works using sudo ! usually I do not need it. Strange !

Comment: Compare `sudo which npm` and `which npm`, are they located in the same directory?

Comment: Yes they are in the same location : usr/local/bin/npm.  why this question ?

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue after updating my node and npm versions. Used this link as guidance: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/update-node-js-version.

I didn't realize my nvm version was also out of date and finally was able to run create-react-app!

You can check your nvm version like so:

```
nvm -ls
```

Then check for the latest version available:

```
nvm ls-remote
```

Finally, install:

```
nvm install [version-number]
```

Hope this helps you as it did for me!